# Execute javascript code ONLY if width is higher than x pixels

Tags: javascript, media-queries, addeventlistener

I'm trying to execute a javascript function ONLY if the width is bigger than 1200pixels.

The code I need to execute works, but the check for the screen size doesn't:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1203) {
            <<<some other code that's working>>>
    }
}, true);
```

All this code is in a javascript file outside the document.ready function.

EDIT: When you drag your screen window around, it isn't working like normal css queries. This is the problem. It works if you refresh your page, but if you change the width of your browser, then it doesn't adjust, it needs the reload right now.

That's my issue.

Comment: Code seems to work fine for me... Do you want it to also fire on load? Because this will only work when the window is resized.

Comment: @Jivings When I resize my screen it doesn't work atm, I need to manually reload the page in order for the code to check for the screen size.

Comment: what browser/version are you seeing this in?

Comment: I just found out that it works when I start from mobile size and resize bigger, but when I start desktop and resize smaller, it doesn't re-update without reloading.

Comment: Here's an example, which works fine in Chrome 40: https://jsfiddle.net/9n5hmpua/embedded/result/

Comment: @Jivings it does in fact hide the div when I go bigger than 500px, but it never re-appears when I go smaller again :/ http://jsfiddle.net/4dnemh2j/3/

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven You've got no `else` clause in your code. So it will never take the `display:none` off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an `else` clause to get the behaviour you want. Otherwise the resize event will only work going one way, as you described.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    // fire when above 1203
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1203) {
      console.log('Greater!');
    }
    // fire when below 1203
    else {
      console.log('Smaller!');
    }
}, true);
```

Here's a link to the fixed jsfiddle that `planet260` wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/4dnemh2j/4/

Here's my example again: https://jsfiddle.net/9n5hmpua

Comment: Thanks for all your trouble, I think maybe my problem is somewhere else then :/ Here's my full code: http://pastebin.com/W3F9HK8F perhaps you see my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `true` you're passing to addEventListener.

See the `useCapture` section here: [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

> Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture

So you want:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1203) {
        <<<some other code that's working>>>
    }
}, false);  <----change here
```

Comment: I changed it to false, but the issue is still here :/

Comment: But the event should be firing directly on window, no bubbling here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  console.log($( window ).width());
  var windowwidth = $( window ).width();
  if (windowwidth > 500) {
      console.log("Greater than 500");
     /*Do your work here*/ 
  }
});
```

Comment: This works, but only when I go from small to big (mobile to desktop)